# Finding a convex upper-bound and lower bound on the expectation of $\ln(1+x)$ when $x\sim \text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$

Tags: integration, statistics, expected-value, gamma-function

I need to evaluate the expectation of $\ln(1+x)$ when $x\sim \text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$. I know that this integral

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(1+x) \right] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+x) \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)}dx$$

has no closed form solution unfortunately and only when $x\gg1$, we can approximate it with $\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(1+x) \right] \approx \mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(x) \right] = \gamma(k) + \ln(\theta)$. However none of these results are convex. I wanted to know if there is any studies on finding convex upper or lower bounds for this integral $\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(1+x) \right]$?!

Any hints and/or references would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're missing an exponential term in your integrand.

Comment: Mathematica gives a closed-form for this integral in terms of Gamma functions.  I am sure I could derive it for you if you're interested in the closed-form.

Comment: Wow, sure, thanks. I edited the equations! Got distracted there.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but unfortunately a solution in terms of Gamma functions is not convex. The Gamma function is log-convex itself, I need a bound that is convex since ultimately I want to optimize such integral with respect to some parameters.

Comment: Gotcha.  I will leave this here in case it ends up being helpful: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+x) \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)}dx=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\theta ^{-k} U\left(k,a+k+1,\frac{1}{\theta }\right)\bigg|_{a=1}$. The derivative can be found [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/20/01/02/).

Comment: @Aaron Hendrickson, thank you for the provided solution, could you please explain how this result is derived, preferably in an answer form. To be honest I don't think it is possible to find a tight convex bound for this monster, I've been searching for a week, a closed form in terms of non-elementary functions is the best we can get and then there is numerical analysis and one dimensional search!

Comment: Is $k$ an integer?

Comment: No, it is a real positive number in general. I don't have any constraint that restricts $k$ to integers.